# Servidor se satura de conexiones

Tags: wordpress, centos7, ip, digitalocean

estoy teniendo un problema con una plantilla de wordpress que al parecer abre muchas conexiones en el servidor, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de arreglar esto o detectar de dónde viene el problema, anexo una imagen de las conexiones y el total que tengo actualmente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto hace que mi servidor que está en DigitalOcean se eleve al 100% de la capacidad del CPU y por ende se cae la pagina que es un wordpress, sin más por el momento agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente con *abre muchas conexiones en el servidor*?

Comment: Es que en determinados momentos se repiten las direcciones, por ejemplo esa última IP hace una hora ya uba en 150 conexiones o peticiones de esa ip.

Comment: Bueno pero eso puede ser un bot o un crawler que está rastreando tu sitio, o un usuario que es fan de tu sitio y lo visita mucho. ¿Por qué te preocupa que haya muchas conexiones? Puedes además verificar con un `whois` a quién pertenece esa IP que se repite mucho. Quizá tengas que hacer algunos bloqueos con [blacklist tipo  6G](https://perishablepress.com/6g/) o de otro modo.

Comment: ¿Cuál servidor web usas?

Comment: Actualmente el wordpress está montado sobre un Centos 7 en DigitalOcean, pero estuve haciendo algunas pruebas con un plugin que se llama CloudFlare para poder verificar que no sean bots los que están generando esas conexiones.
lo que me preocupa es que el servidor esta al 100% del CPU y se termina cayendo despues de un rato.